# What are valid host types when building GMP?

Tags: build, configure, cpu-architecture, gmp

The `configure` script of GMP auto-detects the host type that it will target.  On my machine this is `sandybridge-pc-linux-gnu`.

The host type can be specified manually using `--host`, as described [here](https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options.html).  **What are the valid CPU types I can use instead of `sandybridge`?**  The [manual](https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options.html) only lists old ones (never mentions `sandybridge`, and I am unable to find the full list.

I would like to compile it so that it will also work on older 64-bit CPUs than the one in my machine.

What setting should I use for reasonable performance and broad compatibility on x86-64?

Comment: `--enable-fat` would avoid the question ;-)

Comment: @Marc You're right, but GMP is barely being used in this program and is absolutely not performance critical.  So I'd rather keep binary sizes small.  I saw the `--disable-assembly` flag on the same manual page, but I assumed that the C compiler may still generate instructions that only work with new CPUs.  So I think that alone won't make the result portable.

Comment: (In this case GMP is a dependency of the [Bliss isomorphism checker](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/), which only uses it to compute the size of the automorphism group by multiplying together a few numbers to get a very large number.  The core isomorphism algorithm doesn't use GMP.)

Comment: Use the output of `./configfsf.guess`.